# Can we extract particular PDF data to Excel

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have one Pdf file. I need to extract the particular data in PDF to Excel using c#. Is it possible?

I have written below code for extract pdf

```
private void ExportPDFToExcel(string fileName)
  {
     fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Models/10310.pdf");

     StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
     PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
     //ExportPDFToExcel(fileName);
     for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
     {
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
        currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentText)));
        text.Append(currentText);

     }
     pdfReader.Close();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ReceiptExport.xlsx");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(text);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ReceiptExport.xlsx");
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to extract specific data? What/How/When are you trying to extract specific data? It's very difficult to help you without knowing exactly what you need help with

Comment: Exactly, how can those *particular data* be recognized in the PDF? By position? By font? Some border around them? Some colored background underneath? Tagged in a particular manner? ...

Comment: Hi @mkl  thanks for your comment. I have added the image of pdf. I need to extract the red marked data from pdf to excel using c#

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? And are those information always at the same position?